# Frontend Form for Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, front-end

I want to add frontend post to custom post types. Till now I have figured out how to do it but only to the regular post type(not custom post). I am using [this code.](http://pastebin.com/z5xwe4PA) (*Couldn't paste it here hence please find it at [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/z5xwe4PA)*)

Need to know what code can be added to make the code applicable to custom post type(such as "books" or "places")

Comment: Have you tried changing Line 83? 
Change `'post_type' => 'post',` to `'post_type' => 'YOURCUSTOMCPT',` See Codex article for `wp_insert_post` for reference - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

Comment: That works. That was pretty clear, I'm kinda new to "Post types" and "frontend" so didn't get it. My apologies and Many thanks.

Comment: @nothingtosee as an answer please :)

Comment: Cheers, I've added it as an answer, The Shawn can you mark as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried changing Line 83? Change `'post_type' => 'post', to 'post_type' => 'YOURCUSTOMCPT',` 
See Codex article for `wp_insert_post` for reference - codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

Answer (score -1):

Did you try Gravity forms? http://www.gravityforms.com with this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/gravity-forms-custom-post-types/

Comment: Not yet. Its a paid plugin so sort of avoided it. Also it was easy to get and implement the aforementioned code for regular post(s), works perfectly. Just need to know what to add to make it applicable for custom post types.